# Movie with a war between Russia and the USA witnessed by astronauts on a space station?

Tags: story-identification, space, warfare

Some years ago, I saw a scifi movie from the 70s/80s and I remember the following scene: It's the future, two astronauts (a Russian and an American) are floating above the Earth in a space station. They receive a spoken message from Earth that their nations are at war effective immediately and therefore the astronauts must not see or talk to each other.

I know that this is a very vague description, but I remember that I liked the whole style of the movie. Can anyone remember the name of this movie?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this was [*2010*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_%28film%29)

> On Earth, tensions between the United States and Soviet Union escalate
>  to what is "technically a state of war", and the US government orders
>  Floyd, Curnow, and Chandra to move into Discovery. Both crews plan to
>  leave Jupiter separately when a launch window opens in several weeks.
>  However, Bowman appears and tells Floyd that everybody must leave
>  Jupiter space within two days because "something wonderful" is going
>  to happen. Floyd, shocked to the core by Bowman's appearance, returns
>  to the Leonov to talk to Kirbuk, but then the Monolith suddenly
>  disappears and a growing black spot appears on Jupiter itself. The
>  spot is actually a vast group of Monoliths that are constantly
>  multiplying. The Monoliths begin shrinking Jupiter's volume,
>  increasing the planet's density, and modifying the chemical properties
>  of its atmosphere.